# There has been an error processing your request in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, error, reports

I have installed some plugin.After installing it displaied some error.

How to fix that? I am using **Magento 1.9**

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1558115809
```

I am using magento 1.9 version 
I added this plugin 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/izberg-marketplace-multi-vendor-multi-seller-drop-ship-solution-in-saas.html

Comment: What is your magento version ?

Comment: go to /var/report/ and check the error exact what you are getting

Comment: Also check the magento Compatible whether the plugin has been supported for this version

Comment: please post the exact error which you are getting. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Rename File **local.xml.sample to local.xml** in your **app/etc** directory.

After that it will show what error are you facing .

Also it will display **meaning of Error log record number: 1558115809 After renaming this file .**

Resolve the error which it display and you will get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your site compilation is on So follow below solution

**Solution 1:**

Turn Off the compiler from your terminal steps :

1. Open your terminal /connect your ssh access
2. Go to your magento root via this command `cd \yourpathtomagentoDir`
3. Fire this commnad  `php -f compiler.php disable`
4. After this do compile `php -f compiler.php compile`
5. After this enable compile `php -f compiler.php enable`

**Solution 2:**

1. Go to your module's xml file located in `app/etc/modules` and disable the module
2. Clear the cache
3. Now you are able to login in back end
4. Disable the compiler and install your module
5. Do compile and enable your magento compile

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. you have to go `app\etc` and change the `local` file as `local.xml.sample`

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to file manager in your root folder
2. Go to `app-->etc` folder. Here, you can see the file name as `local.xml.`
3. Rename the file from `local.xml` to `local.xml.sample`
4. Clear the cache.